# Backbone View shouldn't have same data in different instances but does

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope

I have a backbone view that has the following code within its render function (note the 3 `console.log(that.ticketSelector.attributes);`):

```
    if(typeof this.ticketSelector === 'undefined') {
        // TODO: first fetch tickets
        this.ticketSelector = new DataTable({
            collection: that.model.tickets,

            icon: "ticket",
            title: "Tickets",
            customClasses: ["ticket", "subject-selector"],

            columns: [
                {text: 'Name', modelKey: "name", col: 1},
                {text: 'Date', modelKey: "date", col: 2},
                {text: 'Owner', modelKey: "owner", col: 3},
                {text: 'Description', modelKey: "description", col: 4}
            ]
        });
        this.$('.subject-selectors').append(this.ticketSelector.$el);
        this.ticketSelector.render().resize();
    } else {
        this.ticketSelector.render().resize();
    }

    console.log(that.ticketSelector.attributes);

    if(typeof this.alarmSelector === 'undefined') {
        // TODO: first fetch tickets
        this.alarmSelector = new DataTable({
            collection: that.model.alarms,

            icon: "warning-sign",
            title: "Alarms",
            customClasses: ["alarm", "subject-selector"],

            columns: [
                {text: 'Name', modelKey: "name", col: 1},
                {text: 'Date', modelKey: "date", col: 2},
                {text: 'Owner', modelKey: "owner", col: 3},
                {text: 'Description', modelKey: "description", col: 4}
            ]
        });
        this.$('.subject-selectors').append(this.alarmSelector.$el);
        this.alarmSelector.render().resize();
    } else {
        this.alarmSelector.render().resize();
    }

    console.log(that.ticketSelector.attributes);

    if(typeof this.taskSelector === 'undefined') {
        // TODO: first fetch tickets
        this.taskSelector = new DataTable({
            collection: that.model.tasks,

            icon: "tasks",
            title: "Tasks",
            customClasses: ["task", "subject-selector"],

            columns: [
                {text: 'Name', modelKey: "name", col: 1},
                {text: 'Date', modelKey: "date", col: 2},
                {text: 'Owner', modelKey: "owner", col: 3},
                {text: 'Description', modelKey: "description", col: 4}
            ]
        });
        this.$('.subject-selectors').append(this.taskSelector.$el);
        this.taskSelector.render().resize();
    } else {
        this.taskSelector.render().resize();
    }

    console.log(that.ticketSelector.attributes);
```

In the console I see:

```
Object {icon: "ticket", title: "Tickets", columns: Array[4], classes: Array[2]}
Object {icon: "warning-sign", title: "Alarms", columns: Array[4], classes: Array[2]}
Object {icon: "tasks", title: "Tasks", columns: Array[4], classes: Array[2]}
```

Where I would expect:

```
Object {icon: "ticket", title: "Tickets", columns: Array[4], classes: Array[2]}
Object {icon: "ticket", title: "Tickets", columns: Array[4], classes: Array[2]}
Object {icon: "ticket", title: "Tickets", columns: Array[4], classes: Array[2]}
```

Here is my DataTable view:

```
var DataTable = Backbone.View.extend({

tag: 'div',
className: 'data-table',

initialize: function(opts) {
    if(typeof opts.parent !== 'undefined') {
        this.parent = opts.parent;
    }
    if(typeof opts.icon !== 'undefined') {
        this.attributes.icon = opts.icon;
    }
    if(typeof opts.title !== 'undefined') {
        this.attributes.title = opts.title;
    }
    if(typeof opts.columns !== 'undefined') {
        this.attributes.columns = opts.columns;
    }
    if(typeof opts.customClasses !== 'undefined') {
        this.attributes.classes = opts.customClasses;
    }
},

attributes: {},

template: function() {
    var temp;

    $.ajax(root + 'templates/data-table.html', {
        success: function(data) {
            // console.log(data);
            temp = Mustache.compile($(data).filter('#data-table-template').html());
        },

        async: false
    });

    return temp;
}(),

events: {
},

serialize: function() {
    var that = this;
    return {
        root: root,
        icon: that.attributes.icon,
        title: that.attributes.title,
        columns: that.attributes.columns
    };
},

resize: function() {
    var that = this;
},

subView: [],

render: function() {
    var that = this;

    var html = this.template(this.serialize());

    this.$el.html(html);

    if(that.attributes.classes) {
        _.each(that.attributes.classes, function(c) {
            that.$el.addClass(c);
        });
    }

    this.collection.each(function(row) {
        tempView = new DataTableRow({ model: row, parent: that, columns: that.attributes.columns });
        that.subView.push(tempView);
        that.$('.tbody').append(tempView.$el);
        tempView.render();
    });

    this.$('.tbody').mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollInertia: 0,
    });

    return this;
}

});

var DataTableRow = Backbone.View.extend({

tag: 'div',
className: 'tr',

initialize: function(opts) {
    var that = this;

    if(typeof opts.parent !== 'undefined') {
        this.parent = opts.parent;
    }

    if(typeof opts.columns !== 'undefined') {
        var temp = {};
        that.attributes.columns = _.map(opts.columns, function(col) {
            return {
                text: that.model.get(col.modelKey),
                col: col.col
            };
        });
    }
},

attributes: { columns: [] },

template: function() {
    var temp;

    $.ajax(root + 'templates/data-table.html', {
        success: function(data) {
            // console.log(data);
            temp = Mustache.compile($(data).filter('#data-table-row-template').html());
        },

        async: false
    });

    return temp;
}(),

events: {
},

serialize: function() {
    var that = this;
    return {
        root: root,
        columns: that.attributes.columns
    };
},

resize: function() {
    var that = this;
},

render: function() {
    var that = this;

    var html = this.template(this.serialize());

    this.$el.html(html);

    return this;
}

});
```

I know I could get around it by creating different views for each data table, but this should work and I am at a loss why it isn't. Any help here? Thanks.

EDIT: as an attempt to understand this better, here is the underscore extend function:

```
_.extend = function(obj) {
  each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
    if (source) {
      for (var prop in source) {
        obj[prop] = source[prop];
      }
    }
  });
  return obj;
};
```

What makes these attributes attach to the prototype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `attributes` `{}` is on the prototype, so it will be shared across all instances of the object. You need to have an `attributes` object for each instance.

Instead of something like this:

```
var DataTable = Backbone.View.extend({
  attributes: {}
});
```

You need to create a new object on each initialization:

```
var DataTable = Backbone.View.extend({
  attributes: {},
  initialize: function(options){
    this.attributes = {};
  }
});
```

As @muistooshort pointed out, you have this problem for your `subViews` array and `DataTableRow.prototype.attributes` too. Any key-value pairs in the object passed to `extend` are placed on the object's prototype, which means that new instances of the object will all share those attributes. That is how all of your functions end up on each instance, but it also means that everything else does too, so it is up to you to make sure that things are initialized properly for each instance.

#### Edit

`Backbone.View.extend` is unrelated to `_.extend` except that it happens to use it has a helper just like any other code.

- `_.extend` takes multiple objects and copies their properties onto the first one.
- `Backbone.View.extend` takes a single object, and returns a new constructor function that will construct an object that has the object as its prototype, and that also inherits the prototype of the first constructor that `extend` was called on.

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1532

So say you had an object like this:

`Backbone.View` constructor that when called will create a new object that has `Backbone.View.prototype` as its prototype having the standard view methods.

When you do `var DataTable = Backbone.View.extend(newproto_obj)`, you now have this:

`DataTable` constructor that when called will create a new object that has a prototype with the values from `newproto_obj`, and `Backbone.View.prototype` as the prototype of that prototype.

This is called the prototype chain, and it is how JavaScript does its inheritance. When you create a new object, it has no properties of its own unless they are set by Backbone in the constructor or `initialize` functions. If you attempt to access a property on the object and it is not present, it will look to see if its prototype has a property by that name. Because the prototype object is a single common object shared across instances, modifying it will change every instance.

Comment: Might have the same problem with `subViews` too. And the other `attributes`.

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that backbone's extend applied things to the prototype. Backbone uses underscore's extend under the covers it looks like.. Could you explain a little bit about why it is on the prototype? Looking at the underscore code it looks to be just copying attributes. I included the underscore function in my question as an edit